# How can i bind vertex data to GLSL in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, glsl

I make unity program with GLSL shader.
I know how to use shader in openGL window programming, not unity.

in unity document, it say that 'use built-in attribute'. but it's so low version of GLSL.
high version, use like this.

```
    layout(location = 0) in vec3 a_position;
    layout(location = 1) in vec3 a_normal;
    out vec3 v_position_EC;
    out vec3 v_normal_EC;
```

upper version don't support vayring variable and pre-defined variables.
if i set "#version 400", it can be complie.
but any data goes.

i want convert this code to unity c# code.

```
 glGenBuffers(1, &rectangle_VBO);

 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectangle_VBO);
 glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(rectangle_vertices), &rectangle_vertices[0][0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

 // Initialize vertex array object.
 glGenVertexArrays(1, &rectangle_VAO);
 glBindVertexArray(rectangle_VAO);

 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, rectangle_VBO);
 glVertexAttribPointer(LOC_POSITION, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
 glVertexAttribPointer(LOC_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), BUFFER_OFFSET(3 * sizeof(float)));
 glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

 glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
 glBindVertexArray(0);
```

I cant find any document for 'bind' data in unity. it's impossible? 
i want solution or say it cant.

I already complete convert to low version.
but my boss want high version.... please help me!

Answer (score 0):

In unity, you only need to assign the material(shader) to the meshrenderer that needs to be rendered.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshRenderer.html

If you want to write opengl code in unity, you can refer to this demo.btw.

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/graphicsdemos/overview